# Modify JavaScript object properties?

Tags: javascript

```
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    // cube animation
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.05;
}

// call render function to render cube

render().cube.rotation.x += 0.9;
```

I want to access cube.rotation outside of the function. Is this possible?

Comment: where is cube declared ?

Comment: Read the error message(s). Note that 1) inside the function, `cube` will raise a ReferenceError and 2) the function call (`render()`) returns `undefined` (or would, if it ran).

Comment: Yup — in the code you’ve provided,y you can’t access cube from `inside` the function either, because it doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible as long as `cube` is in scope. For example:

```
(function(){
    var cube = {rotation: {x: 0, y: 0}};

    function render() {
        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.05;
    }

    render();

    cube.rotation.x += 0.9; // Valid
})();

cube.rotation.x += 0.9; // NOT Valid
```

If you need to expose cube globally then create a global namespace. In the place where `cube` is declared do:

```
var cube = ...;
...
var NAMESPACE = window.NAMESPACE = window.NAMESPACE || {};
NAMESPACE.cube = cube;
```

Then you can access the cube anywhere using:

```
window.NAMESPACE.cube.rotation.x += 0.9;
```

Replace `NAMESPACE` with the actual name of your namespace.